# Custom pagination in Data Tables without count

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm trying to display data in table using `Data Tables`.
The plugin requires data from server to have the following structure:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 10,
    "recordsFiltered": 100,
    "data": [...]
}
```

But the server returns data without counts:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "data": [...]
}
```

I need simple pagination with `previous` and `next` buttons and suppose it could be implemented without the counts.

For example, to display `N` rows one could query `N + 1` and if the response size equals `N + 1` then the `next` button is available.

Is there any pagination plugin for `Data Tables` that works according to the logic above?

Comment: It seems to me, that the pagination plugins only "style" the pagination functionality while the actual logic *(sending queries and stuff)* is in the datatables code, I'd guess. Is it really that hard to provide the requested totals?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the totals cannot be provided (server implementation detail).

Comment: How large is your dataset? Can you return all records at once and use client-side processing?

Comment: Rolling your own pagination is easy enough but you'd need to have some sort of idea of the length of your data. Also, you'd perhaps not use `serverside` but make repeated ajax calls to first empty and then populate the table with your new data. I've just done something similar with an API which only returned the total number of records and the index of the latest request, so something like `"start": 20, "total": 200`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com no, the table contains thousands of logs.

Comment: @annoyingmouse the info about total count of records is unavailable. But it seems that `next` and `previous` page availability could be inferred it.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be too much of a bother. I've rolled my own this week and the link is here: http://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2017/02/roll-your-own-pagination-with-bootstrap.html You could adapt that to your use case quite easily.